# not receiving push notification from firebase But with Pusher app

Tags: java, ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

i do not get any notification from firebase but when i test with Pusher app i get the notification.

these are my steps i have Done. help me if i have done something wrong.

1_ add notificationService as below.

```
class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {

var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
    self.contentHandler = contentHandler
    bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)

    if let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
        // Modify the notification content here...




        bestAttemptContent.title = "hello"
        bestAttemptContent.body = "this is test"


        contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
    }
}
```

}

2 _ set notificationCenter delegate to self in app delegate

```
        Messaging.messaging().delegate=self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
```

3_ device token for sending notification (i store this to server)

```
   func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

    let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
    // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
    // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
}
```

i send this FCMToken to server Side(java,spring boot)

4_ i have enabled push notification in Capabilities

5_ i have  added .p12 file in cloud messaging of project settings in firebase console but i have big question for this !???? should i login to firebase with my server's account ? or make an account for my self ?? because i have created one for my self.

some tips :

we are a team like server side(JAVA). web , android and ios

which this push notification is working on android but not on ios.

i think i'm doing something in a wrong way.

thank you for reading this topic and helping me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the steps to cross check your issue,

1. Notification Capabilities has to be enabled.
2. Certificate you created on apple member center should enable the push
   notification 
   [image]
3. In firebase console go to settings -> project settings -> cloud messaging -> check the server key

   1. This key and the key what you gave to you server team should be same
   2. Check APNs Authentication Key or APNs Certificates added or not.
   3. If you are using APNs Certificates, that should be same that you generated in the appId in the member center 
      [image]
4. get the fcm token from the xcode console -> go to firebase console -> grow -> cloud messaging -> new notification 
   -> and try test on device. if you receive notification client side (device) has no issues. if not server side has to double check the server key.
5. Add your googleServiceInfo.plist to your project. add the reversed key in your app info.
6. in `Appdelegate`, configure your firebase 
   `FirebaseApp.configure()`

**Update**, As per your question in the comment, am updating this question. 
To make use of NotificationService Extension, you notification must include `mutable-content` property in the notification payload. using fcm api you can do that. put these in the post man,

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

in the headers, add your server key (you can get this from your firebase console)

[image]

in the body add this payload to fire notification. this will trigger your Notification Service Extension.

```
{
    "notification": {
        "title": "1",
        "body": "",
        "click_action": "",
        "icon": "",
        "mutable_content": true,
        "content_available": true
    },
    "registration_ids":["add your fcm token"],
    "data": {}
}
```

[image]

As per the tutorial: 
    https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-10-notification-service-extensions--cms-27550

[image]

Comment: i did not understand number 3.1 . do you mean the FcmToken generate it app delegate ?? must be same with server key ?

Comment: No, if you got to firebase console -> project settings -> cloud messaging, you can find out a ServerKey like this `AAAA-hY_3kw:APA91bEtwFaf3h4xKi6QT1UyfumYhpb2hAWQFhfx2jfHWHiByYf_3yHhvTYIIwF9NV2ZHSiW-HlqydlTlDkURHWR7ms1uWaicbq-6DSk3wxPr5UTMhRjWAiQvN0tZsjHIuxxxxxxxxxx`, that key has to be used to push the notification from the server.

Comment: i'm receiving notifications now which i'm sending manually from fire base console. but i need to modify notification content and using notification Service.but not running my modifying methods

Comment: you mean to say your notification service not getting called ?

Comment: yes. i'm getting notifications.but i need to modify the content.i'm using notification service extension . but not getting called. i'm sending notifications from firebase panel manually for now.but this must be automatically from server

Comment: now it is working. but how can i add mutable-content to my payload ?? there is no payload. server side sends data automatically.how can i add this ?

Comment: you have to tell the severside people to add the `mutable-content` in the payload. no other way. if they are using fcm to push the notification there is a method to add this. thats how we are doing

Comment: it is not working in automatically mode....:(  not getting notification.  only get notifications when i send from firebase Console manually

Comment: as i said your server side people has to add the property. ask them to add. if they don’t know ask them to open a question.  for android they don’t need any property in the payload. if serverside using fcm to push notification. there are lot of tutorials available.

Comment: they added the property.thats the suffering issue @Karthik

Comment: better ask them to create a question. that might give some solutions

Comment: one final question. when i send notification manually from firebase. when i remove mutable-content property it was working too.how is that possible ?

Comment: try removing content available too. then check it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188328/discussion-between-karthik-and-ryan110).

Comment: getting notification from post man but not getting from server side(java).what is the problem? the server keys are the same